# Are there limitations on stacking Boosterpacks for the TI Launchpads?

Tags: embedded, texas-instruments, launchpad

I've read many pdf's about the launchpad but one thing is not clear to me yet:

Can any boosterpack be combined with any other boosterpak?
If not, how can I tell which boards might work together?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most boosterpacks don't come with stackable headers, so  you can't put more than one on. For those that do, whether you can combine them with others depends on what pins they use - if two boosterpacks try to use the same pin for different purposes, stacking them isn't going to work.

Comment: Is there a common way for them to publish which pins they use? Or is the way to find out by going through the specsheets?

Comment: @Toad To the best of my knowledge, your best (and only) option is to check the schematic of each booster you want to use.

Comment: too bad it isn't more like a 'usb interface'. I think it would 'boost' the popularity of packages even more. In any case, thanks for your insights

Comment: @Toad That's tricky to do, since one of the goals is to make expansion boards as simple as possible - you can make an expansion with nothing but passive components. There are ways around this, like using an I2C bus and IO expanders, or clever pin reassignment strategies, but they have to be designed into the system from the start.

Comment: When attaching i2c modules to a board this problem of potentially 'incompatible' boards doesn't exist?

Comment: @Toad If the modules only use the I2C lines, and use unique addresses, then no, there's no issue.